# Reloading modal table appends to existing table and doubles the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal that displays informations about items (dates, etc) in a table. When I click on an item it opens a smaller modal where I can update the items date, which is then updated throught a webservice to the database. then I want to reload the data to show the updated ETA. The way I found to do that is to recall the open function of my modal. But then when I do that the modal reloads and the table is now doubled. So it probably appends to the existing table without clearing the data. How can I clear the content and reload it fresh with the updated data ? Preferably without closing and reopening the modal. Heres my code.

First is the function that saves the change and closes the small modal

```
    $('#btnSaveETAChange').click(function () {
    var dt_eta = document.getElementById('<%=EtaDate.ClientID%>').value;
    var no_item = document.getElementById('<%=ItemNo.ClientID%>').value;
    var no_document = document.getElementById('<%=NoPo.ClientID%>').value;
    var no_line = document.getElementById('<%=LineNo.ClientID%>').value;
    var no_project = document.getElementById('<%=ProjectNo.ClientID%>').value;

    UpdateEta(no_item, dt_eta, no_document, no_line)
    $('#modalUpdateETA').modal('hide');
    $('#modalUpdateETA').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        OpenModaleShortage(no_project);
    });
});
```

This the function that loads the main modal.

```
    function OpenModaleShortage(ProjectNumber) {
    $("#Shortage_body tr").remove();

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/MTL/SEPTOR/wsMTL.asmx/GetProjectOutstandingItems") %>',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{ 'ProjectNumber': '" + ProjectNumber + "'}",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (data) {          
                var rowMaterial = "<tr>"
                    + "<th style='text-align:center; font-size:16px'>Item No</th>"
                    + "<th style='text-align:left; font-size:16px'>Description</th>"
                    + "<th style='text-align:center; font-size:16px'>Shortage</th>"
                    + "<th style='text-align:center; font-size:16px'></th>"
                    + "<th style='text-align:center; font-size:16px'>ETA</th>"
                    + "</tr>";

                $("#Shortage tbody").append(rowMaterial);

                $(data).find('SHORTAGE').each(function (i, productionRow) {
                    try {
                        rowMaterial = "<tr>"
                            + "<td id='no_po' style='display: none; '>" + $(productionRow).find('PO').text() + "</td> "
                            + "<td id='no_line' style='display: none; '>" + $(productionRow).find('LineNO').text() + "</td> "
                            + "<td id='no_item' style='text-align:center; font-size:14px'>" + $(productionRow).find('ItemNo').text() + "</td> "
                            + "<td id='no_project' style='text-align:center; font-size:14px'>" + $(productionRow).find('ProjectNo').text()+ "</td> "
                            + "<td style='text-align:left; font-size:14px'>" + $(productionRow).find('Description').text() + "</td> "
                            + "<td style='text-align:center; font-size:14px'>" + parseInt($(productionRow).find("ProjectShortage").text()) + "</td> "
                            + "<td style='text-align:center; font-size:14px' data-toggle='modal'><div><i style='vertical-align: center;' class='fa fa-calendar'></i></div></td> "
                            + "<td id='dt_eta' style='text-align:center; font-size:14px'>" + $(productionRow).find('ETA1').text().slice(0, 10).trim().replace('-', '.').replace('-', '.') + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>";

                        $("#Shortage tbody").append(rowMaterial);
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        alert(err.message);
                    }
                });

                $('#addShortage').modal('show');
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the best practical answer I've come up with is to rework my page using knockout.js.
(http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro).
By binding my view to observables. I will save the trouble of ever having to deal with those situations again.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easily, it turns out. You'll want to use the jQuery [empty() method](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)
Before you stick any data into id Shortage tbody, just empty that div out. Then, when you append new data in, it should take its place.

Admittedly, I'm uncertain how this will go down with a tbody, so you may wind up needing to delete the whole table and then re-draw the whole table, but that's not a certain thing.

Comment: Yes that should work but for some reason it doesn't for me.